# Laravel /w Ionic JWT authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, ionic-framework, jwt

So I am developing Ionic app with Laravel back-end and using JWT authentication.

My question is...since im using 4 fields when registering a user, and only 2 when logging in (email and pass), I suppose that upon registration the token should be made of only those 2 fields...

This is the working sign up function:

```
public function signUp()
{
    $credentials = Input::all();

    if (User::whereEmail($credentials['email'])->first()) {
        return Response::json([
            'error' => 'User with given e-mail already exists',
        ], 409);
    } elseif (User::wherePhone($credentials['phone'])->first()) {
        return Response::json([
            'error' => 'User with given phone number already exists',
        ], 409);
    } else {
        $user = User::create($credentials);
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

        return Response::json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

However if I change `$credentials = Input::only('email', 'password')` the full user won't be created (since there are fields missing).

But even if I leave `$credentials` as-is, and make combinations like 
`$token = JWTAuth::fromUser(Input::only('email', 'password'))` or parse e-mail and password to JSON, or something similar...I get a "Trying to get a property of non-object" error, or that array is given instead of an object to JWTAuth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JWTAuth::fromUser(Input::only('email', 'password'))` expects a User object.

If you wish to use credentials you can do something like this:

```
    // grab credentials from the request
    $credentials = Input::only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return Response::json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return Response::json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    return Response::json(compact('token'));
```

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens

Comment: I have read the documentation, and this does work...but then my logic is flawed :) I had an idea of storing the token in the DB upon registration, and then when user logs in, the tokens would need to match...but I guess this is a smarter and more reliable solution not to store tokens in DB. Thanks